# Returning true if all items in a list are true, otherwise false

Tags: scala

I want to return true if "inStock" key exists AND all values in the list are true.
If not, then return false.

```
val product = Map("ids" -> List("1" ,"2", "3"), "inStock" -> List("true", "false", "true", "true"))

product.get("inStock").map(x => x.forall(true))  // doesnt' work currently

<console>:13: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Boolean(true)
 required: String => Boolean
```

I should also safely parse the string value to a boolean like:

```
Try(x.toBoolean)
```

Comment: Consider accepting an answer if you consider your question has been solved.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need not convert to Boolean type

```
product.get("inStock").map(_.forall(_ == "true")).getOrElse(false)
```

Beware below line can throw exception if `inStock` key is not present in the map.

```
product("inStock").forall(_ == "true")
```

**Scala REPL**

```
scala> val product = Map("ids" -> List("1" ,"2", "3"), "inStock" -> List("true", "false", "true", "true"))
product: Map[String, List[String]] = Map("ids" -> List("1", "2", "3"), "inStock" -> List("true", "false", "true", "true"))

scala> import scala.util._
import scala.util._

scala> product.get("inStock").map(_.forall(_ == "true")).getOrElse(false)
res7: Boolean = false

scala> product.get("foo").map(_.forall(_ == "true")).getOrElse(false)
res8: Boolean = false
```

## Lurking Danger with NoSuchElementException

```
scala> product("foo").forall(_ == "true")
java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: foo
  scala.collection.MapLike$class.default(MapLike.scala:228)
  scala.collection.AbstractMap.default(Map.scala:59)
  scala.collection.MapLike$class.apply(MapLike.scala:141)
  scala.collection.AbstractMap.apply(Map.scala:59)
  $sess.cmd9$.<init>(cmd9.sc:1)
  $sess.cmd9$.<clinit>(cmd9.sc:-1)
```

## Fool proof way

```
scala> product.get("foo").map(_.forall(_ == "true")).getOrElse(false)
res7: Boolean = false
```

## More typesafe

```
product.get("inStock")
  .toSeq.flatten.map(elem => Try(elem.toBoolean))
  .collect { case Success(value) => value}
  .reduce(_ && _)
```

## for comprehension

Use the fact that Option is an iterable.

```
(for {
    list <- product.get("inStock").iterator
    elem <- list.iterator
    result <- Try(elem.toBoolean).toOption.iterator
  } yield result).reduce(_ && _)
```

Answer (score 2):

This will return the `Boolean` you're looking for.

```
product("inStock").forall(_ == "true")
```

This will return a `Failure` if someone has misspelled "true" or "false", or if there is no "inStock" key in the Map.

```
Try( product("inStock").map(_.toBoolean).reduce(_ && _) )  // Success(false)
```